# Procedimiento almacenado no se ejecuta completamente cuando lo llamo desde PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, xml, stored-procedure, transacciones

Estoy teniendo un problema bastante serio ya que no me deja continuar con el proyecto que estoy desarrollando.

La lógica es la siguiente, subo un archivo de `Excel` al servidor (desde un sistema web) luego leo los datos que están en el archivo de `Excel` y genero un `XML`, ese `XML` lo envío a un procedimiento almacenado en `SQL Server 2008`. 
Verifico con el `SQL Server Profiler` que se esté haciendo la llamada al procedimiento almacenado y todo correcto hasta allí.

Como en mi `SP` tengo una transacción entonces no inserta nada en la base de datos de lo que le envío en el `XML`. Si comento la transacción en cambio se guarda solo la mitad de lo que le envío en el `XML`.

Si ejecuto directamente el `SP` desde `SQL Server` y le envío el mismo `XML`, se guarda todo sin ningún problema.

¿Alguien sabe qué está sucediendo y cómo podría resolver este problema?

De antemano, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

descubrí que el problema se debía a que no tenía activado el 
**set nocount on**.
Puse al inicio de la transacción el *set nocount on* y al final *set nocount off* y funcionó de maravillas.
Gracias a todos

Comment: acepta la respuesta -> click en el check!